# Is there a way/ method to check/ return a value everytime the camera gets accessed by any of the processes/ apps using open-cv Python?

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I am trying to build a **Python script that returns True every time the camera gets opened by an app** and I came across several Open-CV scripts but could not get them working for this purpose. Also I tried using the cam.isOpened() inside an infinite loop to check if it worked while accessing the camera through another app, as given below, but it did not work.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    if cam.isOpened():
        return("True")
```

Is there a way this task could be achieved?

Comment: instead of return("True") try with import sys
sys.exit(-1)

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV can't do this. it's not meant to. you're using its APIs wrong.

you need **operating system APIs** if you want to check whether anything currently accesses a camera.